# PugsJs add extra classes to mixin

Tags: navigation, pug

How can I add some extra classes to a mixin that already have classes.
Here is my code, and I'm triying to add the third parameter but it doesn't work.

```
mixin item(title, url, extraClasses)
    mixin linkA
        a.nav-link(href=url)= title
    li.nav-item.mr-auto.#{extraClasses}(class=title === activeMenu ? 'active' : '')
        +linkA

ul.navbar-nav.ml-auto
    each val in ['Menu1', 'Menu2', 'Menu3', 'Menu4']
      if val !=='Menu1'      
        +item(val, href='/' + val.toLowerCase() + '.html', 'test1')
      else
        +item(val, href='/' + val.toLowerCase() + '.html', 'test2')
```

See it live under:
https://codepen.io/Bizboss/pen/zYYwoZP?editors=1011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`&attributes`](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-attributes) mixin syntax to easily pass additional classes to an element in a mixin.

Here's a simplified example:

```
mixin item(title, url, isActive)
  li(class= isActive ? 'active' : '')&attributes(attributes)
    a(href= url) #{title}

ul
  +item('Home', '/', true).myClass
  +item('About', '/about', false)
  +item('Contact', '/contact', false).foo.bar
```

This will render:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active myClass">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="foo bar">
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```